# How To Use Matlab GUI Slider Trough

Tags: matlab, user-interface, slider, matlab-guide

I am trying to slide through images that I loaded into the GUI. When images are loaded into the GUI, I updated the slider parameters like this.

**part of the "function" for image loading**

```
    if handles.nImages > 1
        set(handles.frameSlider,'Min',1,'Max',handles.nImages,'Value',1)
        handles.sliderStep = [1 1]/(handles.nImages - 1);
        set(handles.frameSlider,'SliderStep',handles.sliderStep)
    end
```

Then trying to slide through images and the slider arrow keys work fine but the pulling the slider trough doesn't work when I did this. When I pull the slider trough, the pull is smooth without any step-incremented sensations. It is giving me this error: **`Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals`**. I think this is happening because when I pull the trough, I am setting it at `values` between the allowable slider increments since the pull is not step-incremented.

**part of the "function" for slider pulling**

```
sliderPosition = get(handles.frameSlider,'Value');
imagesc(handles.imageListPhs{indexes})
```

What could be the error?

Comment: If you're not going to provide a [mcve] you could, at the very least, explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: @excaza Edited the question.

Comment: What is unclear about the error message?

Comment: @excaza There is nothing unclear about it. What is unclear for me is how to apply discrete step increments when pulling the trough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step size of the slider only governs how it behaves when the user clicks the arrow buttons or inside the slider trough. The location of the thumb when the user drags it is not governed by the step size so it will most likely return a non-integer, which cannot be used as an index. You will need to use a rounding function, like [`round`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html), [`ceil`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html), [`floor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html), or [`fix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fix.html) to convert the slider value into one that is valid for indexing.

Consider the following example:

```
function testcode
nA = 15;

myfig = figure('MenuBar', 'none', 'ToolBar', 'none', 'NumberTitle', 'off');

lbl(1) = uicontrol('Parent', myfig, 'Style', 'text', ...
                'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.1 0.7 0.8 0.2], ...
                'FontSize', 24, 'String', 'Selected Value:');

lbl(2) = uicontrol('Parent', myfig, 'Style', 'text', ...
                'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.1 0.4 0.8 0.2], ...
                'FontSize', 24, 'String', 'Rounded Value:');

uicontrol('Parent', myfig, 'Style', 'Slider', ...
          'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.1 0.1 0.8 0.2], ...
          'Min', 1, 'Max', nA, 'SliderStep', [1 1]/(nA - 1), 'Value', 1, ...
          'Callback', {@clbk, lbl});
end

function clbk(hObject, ~, lbl)
slider_value = get(hObject, 'Value');
slider_value_rnd = round(slider_value);

set(lbl(1), 'String', sprintf('Selected Value: %.2f\n Can I Index with this? %s', ...
    slider_value, canIindexwiththis(slider_value)));
set(lbl(2), 'String', sprintf('Rounded  Value: %.2f\n Can I Index with this? %s', ...
    slider_value_rnd, canIindexwiththis(slider_value_rnd)));

set(hObject, 'Value', slider_value_rnd);  % Snap slider to correct position
end

function [yesno] = canIindexwiththis(val)

try
    A(val) = 0;
catch
    yesno = 'No!';
    return
end
yesno = 'Yes!';
end
```

which illustrates the process:

[image: yay]

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation.